# I am not able to bring the pointer to start of a TXT file had been read once. Can someone help me out with the code i have posted?

Tags: java

```
int count=0;
int checker=0;
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("readFTF.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

    String strLine;
    String testStr;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
testStr = in.readLine();
testStr=testStr.toUpperCase();

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {   // using this i am reading a fill till null how to bring back the pointer to the start of the file after it have reached to the end of the file?

 char ch=strLine.charAt(0);
 switch(ch)
 {
     case 'Q':
            strLine=strLine.substring(1);

            for (int m=0; m<len; m++) 
            {
                if(strLine.contains(result[m]))
                    count++;
            }
            if(count==len)
            {checker++;
               count=0;}
            break;
     case 'R':
            if(checker>0)
            {
                strLine=strLine.substring(1);
                System.out.println(strLine);
                checker=0;
            }   
            break;
     default:

            break;      
 }
}
```

I have a file named readFTF . I am building sort of a searching program . User enter a string which is to be searched in the file linearly . When one string is searched the pointer is placed to the end of the file. When again user starts to search a String , it is not able to search in the file as the pointer is at the end of the file. How can i manage to bring back the pointer to the file line of the file for each iteration ?

Comment: Close and re-open it.

Comment: You could try to use [reset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#reset())

Comment: If the file is small, consider just loading it into memory before doing your searching.

Comment: Is this all your code? It looks like you aren't even using the value you get from System.in

Comment: This might answer you [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/randomaccessfile_seek.htm). `java.io.RandomAccessFile` use `seek(position)`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

1. Close & reopen the file like you did in the begining.

Or

2. Use [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)